# Does the "ngx_http_subrequest" polluted the response?

Tags: nginx

I find a question in **ngx_http_auth_request_module** in nginx

#### nginx.conf

```
...
auth_request /auth;

location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://dev.auth.com:20007;
    ...
}
...
```

source code from nginx-1.11.5/src/http/modules/ngx_http_auth_request_module.c:206

```
if (ngx_http_subrequest(r, &arcf->uri, NULL, &sr, ps,
                       NGX_HTTP_SUBREQUEST_WAITED)
    != NGX_OK)
{
    return NGX_ERROR;
}

/*
 * allocate fake request body to avoid attempts to read it and to make
 * sure real body file (if already read) won't be closed by upstream
 */

sr->request_body = ngx_pcalloc(r->pool, sizeof(ngx_http_request_body_t));
if (sr->request_body == NULL) {
    return NGX_ERROR;
}

sr->header_only = 1;

ctx->subrequest = sr;
```

when I set **sr->header_only = 0**, the brower revieve some invalid data.

The data are seens like this

```
falseHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.11.5 
Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 06:52:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 44
Last-Modified: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 12:08:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5ae312ba-2c"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The string "false" is the response from "proxy_pass http://dev.auth.com:20007;"

What's this scene  really comes from? And how can I get the valid data with "sr->header_only" set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I met an API **ngx_http_discard_request_body** could remove this scene.

> psedu-code

```
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_blockrc_subrequest_post_handler(
ngx_http_request_t *r, void *data, ngx_int_t rc){
 ...

 ngx_http_discard_request_body(r);

 return rc;
}
```